# How to pass parameter to implicit controller in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.3

In both laravel 4.2 and laravel 5.3, there is an option in route to use implicit controller. The syntax are the same for both version.

```
Route::controller('myroute', 'myDearController');
```

So the URL will be:

```
http://my.domain.com/myroute/function-name/parameter1/parameter2
```

In laravel 4, the controller will look like:

```
//..... Some other controller related syntax ......
public function getFunctionName($parameter1, $parameter2) {
    $inputs = Input::all();
    dd($inputs);
}
//..... Some other controller related syntax ......
```

However, in laravel 5, to get the GET input, it takes up a parameter place, so I tried to make something like this:

```
//..... Some other controller related syntax ......
public function getFunctionName(Request $request, $parameter1, $parameter2) {
    $inputs = $request->all();
    dd($inputs);
}
//..... Some other controller related syntax ......
```

However, the URL returns `The site can't be reached`. I tried switching the position,

```
//..... Some other controller related syntax ......
public function getFunctionName( $parameter1, $parameter2, Request $request) {
    $inputs = $request->all();
    dd($inputs);
}
//..... Some other controller related syntax ......
```

It does not work. I know I can add the line `Route::get('myroute/function-name/{$parameter1}/{$parameter2}', 'myDearController@getFunctionName')` to the route file, but besides explicitly specify in the route file, is there a default way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

With explicit routes, it should be `{parameter}` instead of `{$parameter}`.
so,

```
Route::get('myroute/function-name/{parameter1}/{parameter2}', 'myDearController@getFunctionName')
```

Comment: It seems you master laravel. I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047583/how-to-add-dynamic-dropdown-list-column-on-laravel-5-3-registration

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `::controller` anymore, so you'll need to create explicit routes for Laravel 5 apps and there is no default way to do what `::controller` did in 4.2. You can look at [Resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) which allow you to use some implicit routes for CRUD.

> Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code.

Comment: How does that line indicate Route::controller no longer works? As a matter of fact, I am using Route::controller and it works fine except the part of passing parameter.

Comment: In 5.3 it will give you `Method controller does not exist` error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('myroute', 'myDearController');
```

If you then do **php artisan route:list** you'll see a list of all your routes.