# How to add dynamic dropdown list column on Laravel 5.3 registration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to create a dropdown list where the data retrieved from the database, ie dropdown level. 
the value of the dropdown level is taken from the table level.

My register controller is like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

My registerusers(vendor) is like this :

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

My register view is like this :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/register') }}">

    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Full Name">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>

        @if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>

        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>

        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>

        @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms</a>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Register</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</form>
```

I get the code : https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/adminlte-generator/tree/5.3

of the code, it appears that a register view in the call of registerusers (vendor)

how to call a table in the database to be stored in variables and sent to view the register?

if I had to edit registerusers (vendor)?

How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to override `showRegistrationForm()` method. So, copy-paste this method from vendor to `RegisterController` and work with it there:

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    // Do something here.

    return view('auth.register');
}
```

Also, do not make any changes in `vendor` directory.

Comment: It's great. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You should not write any code in vendor's file,  rather than you may use  [service injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#service-injection) or [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers) to serve your purpose.